# Difficulty with CodingBat String Exercises

Tags: java, string

I'm taking an online AP Computer Science course this year and we just started working with Strings and the relevant methods that go along with it. Part of my assignment this week is to complete some of the CodingBat String 3 practice problems and I'm stuck on sumNumbers. This code is supposed to take a string and add all of the numbers(not digits) in it. For example, "13tet6" should output 19. I commented my code to show how I thought this code should run.

```
  public int sumNumbers(String str) {
  int place, length, sum;
  length = str.length(); //Gets length of string
  place=0;
  sum=0;
  String number = "";

  while(place<length){               //This loop will stop when we reach the last character of the string         

    while(Character.isDigit(place)){ //This checks if the char at place is a digit
      number+=str.charAt(place);     //If so it adds it to the String number
      place++;                       //This moves along the string to check the next character
    }

    if(!(number=="")) //This will only add the number to the sum if it has a number stored
      sum+=Integer.parseInt(number); //This will add the number to the sum by
                                     //Converting the string to an integer
    number=""; //This resets the number string so it can read the next number
    place++; //This moves the loop along
  }

  return sum;
}
```

This should output the sum of the numbers in the string but it always outputs 0. I replaced the if statement at the bottom with one that would add 1 to sum everytime number had "" stored in it. It always output the length of the string so I know that the while(Character.isDigit(place)) loop is never running correctly. I don't know why, I am probably just missing something simple.

Comment: For one thing, `Character.isDigit(str.charAt(place))` (and check the bounds too).

Comment: For another, `number += Character.getNumericValue(str.charAt(place));` (and don't forget to multiply it by 10 first).

Comment: @AndyTurner he operates on sequences of strings and performs `Integer.parseInt`, he doesn't need to do it character-by-character. Your first observation about `Character.isDigit(place)` is correct though.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks for catching the    `Character.isDigit(str.charAt(place))` mistake, I was able to fix it off of that.

Comment: @Obicere oh, it's a string. Well, OK, but why use `parseInt` if you can just get the numeric value. It avoids the quadratic concatenation.

Comment: Also: `!(number=="")` should be `!number.equals("")`, or, more easily, `!number.isEmpty()`.

Comment: @AndyTurner true. Don't forget that CodingBat was around long before Java 8. Its also not about getting the answer, its more about about the process. Being able to work out these problems and get into the right mindset is great. Its actually great to see Conner trying these out and I applaud that.

Comment: @ConnerAwald a tip: never concatenate a string in a loop with `+`. Use a `StringBuilder`. Or - better - don't, and just use an int to point to the start of the string, and increment another int which points to the end of the string. Extract the string at the end using `str.substring(start, end)`.

Comment: @AndyTurner So something like this? `start=place;
    while(place<length && Character.isDigit(str.charAt(place)))
      place++;
    end=place;  number=str.substring(start,end);`

Comment: @AndyTurner Your observation about `!(number=="")` isn't quite right.  This is one of those edge cases where comparison with `==` is OK, since if the string's value is `""`, it's because it hasn't changed since the interned literal `""` was assigned to it.  Of course, it's a dangerous habit for a beginner to get into.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I normally use `*.equals()` for comparisons but I was confused on why the code wasn't working in the first place so I was changing around everything just to try and get it to work, just happened to leave it there. What makes using `==` so bad though?

Comment: Usually, `==` doesn't work for comparing `Strings`, because it checks whether two `String` variables refer to the same `String` object; and usually, what you want to do is check whether two different `String` objects have the same contents.  That's why we have the `equals` method.

Comment: A more clean and easier to read solution would be to use the String split function with all non integer characters as your regex's to filter out. Then you can loop through that array and sum all the values. Hope this helps!

Comment: @BaileyTincher If you post that as an answer, I will upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Your second while loop is wrong.
You check Character.isDigit(place) but this is always true since you are checking a number! Place is the position in the string you are checking.
This should be:

```
Character.isDigit(str.charAt(place))
```

This introduces a second problem.  As your last character is a number the while loop will check the next value but there isn't any since it goes out of bounds.
So add a check and your while will look like this:

```
while (!(str.length() <= place) && Character.isDigit(str.charAt(place)))
```